# javascript detect if being run in hta

Tags: javascript, web-applications, hta

We'd like to allow our users to download an hta file and run our web app inside it, and have certain pages detect that they are running in an hta file and offer additional features that a web app wouldn't normally have permission to do.

How can I simply detect if the page is being browsed from an hta file container?

Answer (score 4):

`window.location.protocol=='file:'` would indicate a local page but that could be a local
html page or a local hta.

I'm thinking `window.external` may be different in each context.
So making and opening `a.htm` and `a.hta` containing:

```
<script>document.write(window.external)</script>
```

We get:

- IE: `[object]`
- FireFox: `[xpconnect wrapped (nsISupports, nsISidebar, nsISidebarExternal, nsIClassInfo)]`
- Chrome: `[object Object]`
- HTA: `null`

So, `isHTA=(window.external==null)` would indicate the HTA context.

Or, `isHTA=false;try{isHTA=(window.external==null)}catch(e){}`

To be on the safe side, since I have only tested current versions of IE, FF, and Chrome and who knows what the other browsers will do.

Comment: this works great, but sadly in safari on windows `window.external` is also null! :(

Answer (score 2):

What about just:-

```
 var isHTA = (document.all && top.document && (top.document.getElementsByTagName('application')[0]));
```

Comment: This return false (despite HTA being available) when run in a popup opened from an HTA application. You have to check hta:application as well to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

HTAs are unique in how they populate the DOM with the <HTA:APPLICATION> tag.  I use the following to grab the HTA object:

```
var hta;
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("APPLICATION");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i+=1) {
    if ("hta" === elements[i].scopeName.toString().toLowerCase()) {
        hta = elements[i];
        break;
    }
}

// To test if the page is an HTA:
var isHta = (undefined !== hta);
```

In other browsers, you will have to use the full tag name to access the same object:

```
// For Firefox/Chrome/IE
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("HTA:APPLICATION");
```

Comment: Other browsers support running HTA files?

Comment: rjmunro: I'm not aware of anything other than mshta.exe supporting HTAs.  However, the tag is still available in the DOM.  I find this useful when providing HTAs from an HTTP server - I can serve them as an HTML document that displays instructions in other browsers on how to run it as an HTA.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but wouldn't just looking at window.location work?

Comment: No. Although the app is opened by an hta file (which contains the login screen), once logged in, the users are browsing normal html files of the web app. Window.location just gives the users current location.

Answer (score 0):

This might fit the bill. Verifying the attributes could be removed.

```
<hta:application id="myHTA"/>
<script>
alert("isHTA = " + isHTA("myHTA"));

function isHTA(htaId) {
  var retval = false;
  var hta = window[htaId];
  if (!hta) {
    // hta wasn't defined
  } else if (hta.scopeName != "hta") {
    // hta:application
  } else if (hta.nodeName != "application") {
    // hta:application
  } else if (hta.tagName != "application") {
    // hta:application
  } else {
    retval = true;
    // attributes only a real hta would have
    var attribKeys = [
      "applicationName",
      "border",
      "borderStyle",
      "caption",
      "commandLine",
      "contextMenu",
      "icon",
      "innerBorder",
      "maximizeButton",
      "minimizeButton",
      "scroll",
      "scrollFlat",
      "selection",
      "showInTaskBar",
      "singleInstance",
      "sysMenu",
      "version",
      "windowState"
    ];
    for (var i=0;i<attribKeys.length;i++) {
      var attribKey = attribKeys[i];
      if (!hta.attribKey === undefined) {
        retval = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return retval;
}

</script>
```

Comment: This would only work if you know the id of the hta being used.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `commandLine` property of the HTA-Application object is the best method to see if you are running as real HTML-Application, because this property is only available in the mshta.exe.

You need to get the HTM-Application object to check this property. If you don't know the ID of the object you can use this code:

```
// Check if running in a HTML-Application
var isHTA = false;
var htaApp = document.getElementsByTagName("HTA:APPLICATION")
if (!htaApp.length) {
    htaApp = document.getElementsByTagName("APPLICATION");
}
if (htaApp.length == 1 && htaApp[0]) {
    isHTA = typeof htaApp[0].commandLine !== "undefined";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

guess not many people still using HTA nowadays, anyway, I think the below should cover all the scenarios:

```
<script language=javascript>
  var VBScriptVersion = "";
  function getVBScriptVersion() {
    var firstScriptBlock = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    var tmpScript = document.createElement('script');
      tmpScript.setAttribute("language", "VBScript");
      tmpScript.text = 'VBScriptVersion = ScriptEngineMajorVersion & "." & ScriptEngineMinorVersion';
      tmpScript.async = false;
      tmpScript.onload = function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    firstScriptBlock.parentNode.insertBefore(tmpScript, firstScriptBlock);
    return VBScriptVersion;
  }

  var isHTA = (getVBScriptVersion()!="" && window.external==null);
</script>
```